# Luggage storage options around Edinburgh Haymarket

Tags: luggage-storage, edinburgh

I need to stash my bag away in Edinburgh for a couple of hours on Sunday. I will stay close to Haymarket station so I am looking for an option in that area. There seems to be no storage facility in the station itself. I also found that there are storage options at Waverley and at the main bus station. Are there any options close(r) to Haymarket?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently stayed at the  [Tune hotel Haymarket](http://tunehotels.com/my/en/our-hotels/edinburgh-scotland/), directly opposite the Haymarket train station. (Also where the Tram-stop to the airport is)

They have a sign at the door, proclaiming that they will store luggage, *also for non-guests*, for a fee of a few pounds per day. (updated as per froderick's comment: GBP 5,- which I believe was per-item).

This service isn't listed on their website. that only lists the generic "luggage storage", which implies, in this case incorrectly, "guests-only".

Comment: Perfect! The cost is £5.

Comment: Glad it helped! and thanks for reporting back, I've included your price in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

There are lockers at [Edinburgh Bus Station](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Edinburgh+Bus+Station/@55.9537483,-3.1935379,15.51z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x4887c78e08751ca5:0xc9562793aa7c7f58!2sEdinburgh+Bus+Station,+Edinburgh!8m2!3d55.9557924!4d-3.1916138!3m4!1s0x4887c78e09a8e7f1:0x4e7b39901b1fe966!8m2!3d55.9554766!4d-3.1914029) near St Andrew Square.

> luggage lockers - (can hold multiple bags) £5 small, £6.50 medium, £8
>   large for each 12 hour period

Its not very close to Haymarket and if you were considering something more central then [Waverley station luggage storage](https://www.networkrail.co.uk/edinburgh-waverley-station/facilities/) is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

The [conference centre](http://www.cvent.com/rfp/edinburgh-hotels/edinburgh-international-conference-centre/venue-b809e71a48454d13b54ba2cb7a5d25e3.aspx) has luggage storage, ask them whether you could use it. It's half a mile which is quite a bit with luggage, you can take the number two bus, two stops.

Comment: Presumably @chx means the number 2 bus - completely unnecessary to take though, EICC is an 8 minute walk from Haymarket.

Comment: Sorry, I was google mapping it half asleep :) fixed.